# Allow conditional class inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, encapsulation, abstraction

This is a question asked to me in an interview.
I have one class say EmployeeClass with two method. EmployeeDetails, SalaryDetails.
Now I have two More Class Employee and Hr. My need is when I create employee object only EmployeeDetails() method should be accessible and when when i create HR class both EmployeeDetails() and SalaryDetails() should be accessiable. I need to define a prototpe using all solid principle.

```
Class EmployeeClass 
{
    EmployeeDetails();
    SalaryDetails();
}
```

and:

```
Class Employee
{
}
Class Hr
{
}
```

and:

```
void Main()
{
    var employee = new Employee();
    employee.EmployeeDetails(); // Only Employee Details is visible

    var hr= new HR();
    hr.EmployeeDetails();
    hr.SalaryDetails(); // Both EmployeeDetails() and 
                        // SalaryDetails() should be visible.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really how inheritance is designed to work. If some derived classes will inherit only some methods from base class, then it would be violation of Liskov substitution principle. [What is an example of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

But you can inherit interface. Let me show an example.

These are interfaces. Pay attention to `IHr` interface. `IHr` inherits `IEmployee` interface:

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    string GetEmployeeDetails();
}

public interface IHr: IEmployee
{
    string SalaryDetails();
}
```

And its concrete implementations:

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public string GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return "Employee. EmployeeDetails";
    }
}

public class Hr : IHr
{
    public string GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return "Hr. EmployeeDetails";
    }

    public string SalaryDetails()
    {
        return "Hr. SalaryDetails";
    }
}
```

And you can use them like this:

```
IEmployee employee = new Employee();
employee.GetEmployeeDetails();

IHr hr = new Hr();
hr.SalaryDetails();
hr.GetEmployeeDetails();
```